# How to disable Horizontal scroll on a website NavBar with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I don't want to disable my horizonal scroll, I want it. Just that I want to remove scroll from certain elements like my NavBar, when I scroll, The Navbar also moves, and that makes it look ugly, I just want to enable horizontal scroll on a certain part of my site, (For Ex: A Table)

For Ref:
[image: Normal]

[image: When Scrolled Right]

Comment: Is your navbar fixed? if its fixed try to put left:0 right:0 on your navbar and try width:100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable scrolling on html/body and add it to your table like below

```css
table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* Needs to be adjusted accordingly */
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tag in css
overflow-x: hidden;